# Finding target sum of two numbers in array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, loops

Im getting errors I can't solve :

> In main -> assignment to expression with array type
>
> In function 'twoSum':
>    error: request for member 'length' in something not a structure or union
>        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
>
> error: expected expression before ']' token
>                    return arrayR[]{i, j};
>
> In function 'main':
>   TwoSum.c:27:13: error: assignment to expression with array type
>        results = twoSum(array, 5, 3);

```
int *twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++)
        {
            int arrayR[2];

            if (nums[j] == target - nums[i])
            {
                return arrayR[]{i, j};
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *results[2];
    results = twoSum(array, 5, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks so much for any help

Comment: You should tag a language (C or C++?).

Comment: It looks like you are used to Java and now have to write in C/C++ that requires more explicit effort when working with memory including arrays. The proper thing to do is to learn who the language you use works and it depends on whether it is C or C++.

Comment: What language are you trying to use? Pick a language and then look up "how to pass arrays in [language]". You need to understand the basics of the language you're using before we can help with any specific issue. Then try asking another question with only a single issue. At the moment what you've shown is a long way from being able to "Finding target sum of two numbers in array".

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work and produce expected results.

As other comments say, you should learn concept of pointer and memory management in C/C++. There is nothing similar can be find in another languages (Java, C# and other), so it will be new concept for you.

```
void twoSum(int *nums, int size,  int numsSize, int target, int * res)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (nums[j] == target - nums[i])
            {
                res[0] = i;
                res[1] = j;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int results[2];
    twoSum(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]), 5, 3, results);

    return 0;
}
```